# Javascript cache busting not yielding results in Firefox

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I'm relatively new to web programming, and I've searched tirelessly for 2 days for what I feel are relevant terms for this problem.

Currently I'm having an issue with a singular test client not loading the correct javascript file version from the server.

I'm cache busting this file with the server version in the query string, and it works for this person in chrome and IE but for some reason Firefox is using the old file.

When I look at the Web Console, I see it load the correct file (with correct server version in query string), and when I go into the file that is loaded, I see all the correct, updated code.

If anyone can shed light on this issue I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: So Firefox has the correct resource URL and fetches the correct content but still runs the old code somehow? That doesn't sound possible, are you perhaps missing something?

Comment: I don't see how I could be, this has worked for 3 iterations of debug code/alerts with 3 people on all major browsers, and for this person on all other browsers except firefox.  I'm convinced that this is a local machine issue, but I'm just looking for insight into how this could be possible.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some of the offending code?

Comment: Found the issue, it was loading two versions of the same file, one with cache busting javascript and one without, loading a very old file.  Depending on which machine was running the code, it would load in a different order.  So for most of us it was loading the old file, then overwriting with the cache busted file.  Vice versa for our problem child.  Thanks for the help/attempted help.